# How to refresh the Gallery images?

Tags: gallery, child-theme

I am using The Ken theme for one of my client, and they want to keep refreshing the Gallery images every time the page load. I could see mk_gallery.php files, as I am not hard code PHP developer so can any one help me where and what code needs to put to keep refreshing the images from pre selected images.

Hope this is possible. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            "style" => 'grid',
            'enable_title' => 'true',
            'structure' => 'column',
            'masonry_style' => '',
            'item_spacing' => '8',
            "images" => '',
            "height" => '',
            "column" => 4,
            'image_quality' => 1,
            "margin_bottom" => 20,
            'thumb_style_width' => 700,
            'thumb_style_height' => 380,
            'hover_scenarios' => 'overlay',
            'scroller_dimension' => 400,
            "el_class" => '',
            'item_id' => '',
        ), $atts ) );


if ( $images == '' ) {

    echo do_shortcode('[mk_message_box type="warning"]No media attachments are selected for image gallery shortcode.[/mk_message_box]');

    return null;
}


$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post__in'=> explode( ',', $images ),
            'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,
            'post_status' => null,
            'order'=>'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
            'numberposts' => -1
            );

$id = uniqid();

$item_id = (!empty($item_id)) ? $item_id : 1409305847;


$output = $final_output = $column_css = $item_width = $slide_item = $thumb_item = $first_loop_css = '';

$scroller_css = array('','','','');

global $mk_settings;
$grid_width = $mk_settings['grid-width'];
$content_width = $mk_settings['content-width'];

if ( is_singular() ) {
    global $post;
    $layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_layout', true );
} else {
    $layout == 'full';
}




if($style == 'grid') {

    if($structure == 'column') {

        switch ( $column ) {
        case 1:
            if ( $layout == 'full' ) {
                $width = $grid_width;
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            } else {
                $width = (($content_width / 100) * $grid_width);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : 350;
            }
            $column_css = 'one-column';
            break;
        case 2:
            if ( $layout == 'full' ) {
                $width = round($grid_width/2);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            } else {
                $width = round((($content_width / 100) * $grid_width)/2);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            }
            $column_css = 'two-column';
            break;
        case 3:
            if ( $layout == 'full' ) {
                $width = round($grid_width/3);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            } else {
                $width = round((($content_width / 100) * $grid_width)/3);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            }
            $column_css = 'three-column';
            break;

        case 4:
            if ( $layout == 'full' ) {
                $width = $grid_width/4;
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            } else {
                $width = (($content_width / 100) * $grid_width)/4;
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            }
            $column_css = 'four-column';
            break;
        case 5:
            if ( $layout == 'full' ) {
                $width = $grid_width/5;
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height :  $width;
            } else {
                $width = round((($content_width / 100) * $grid_width)/5);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            }
            $column_css = 'five-column';
            break;

        case 6:
            if ( $layout == 'full' ) {
                $width = round($grid_width/6);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height :  $width;
            } else {
                $width = round((($content_width / 100) * $grid_width)/6);
                $height = !empty( $height ) ? $height : $width;
            }
            $column_css = 'six-column';
            break;
        }

        $width = $width*$image_quality;
        $height = $height*$image_quality;

    } else {

        $width = $scroller_dimension - 1;
        $height = $scroller_dimension - 1;
        $scroller_css = array('swiper-container mk-swiper-slider ', 'swiper-wrapper ', 'swiper-slide', ' data-freeModeFluid="true" data-slidesPerView="auto" data-pagination="false" data-freeMode="true" data-mousewheelControl="true" data-direction="horizontal" data-slideshowSpeed="4000" data-animationSpeed="400" data-directionNav="false" ');
        $item_width = ' style="width:'.$scroller_dimension.'px"';
    }

        $i = 0;
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $i++;
                $title = $attachment->post_title;
                $image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full', true );
                $image_src = bfi_thumb( $image_src_array[ 0 ], array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height, 'crop'=>true));

                $zoom_icon ='<a href="'.$image_src_array[0].'" title="'.$title.'" rel="gallery-'.$id.'" class="mk-lightbox theme-rounded-icon"><i class="mk-nuance-icon-search"></i></a>';

                $output .='<li class="'.$scroller_css[2].'"'.$item_width.'><div class="item-holder mk-gallery-item">';


                $output .='<div class="featured-image '.$hover_scenarios.'-hover"><img alt="'.$title.'" title="'.$title.'" src="' . mk_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src, $width, $height) .'" />';
                $output .='<div class="hover-overlay"></div>';
                    $output .='<a href="'.$image_src_array[0].'" title="'.$title.'" rel="gallery-'.$id.'" class="mk-lightbox">';
                    $output .= '<div class="gallery-meta">';
                    $output .= '<i class="mk-theme-icon-plus"></i><div class="clearboth"></div>';
                    $output .= ($enable_title == 'true') ? '<div class="the-title">'.$title.'</div>' : '';
                    $output .= '</div></a>';


                $output .='</div>';

                $output .='</div></li>';




            }
        }

        $final_output .= '<div id="gallery-'.$id.'" style="margin-bottom:'.$margin_bottom.'px" class="mk-gallery '.$style.'-style '.$structure.'-structure '.$scroller_css[0].$column_css.' '.$el_class.'"'.$scroller_css[3].'><ul class="'.$scroller_css[1].'">' . $output . '</ul><div class="clearboth"></div></div>';

} else if($style == 'thumb') {

        $width = $thumb_style_width;
        $height = $thumb_style_height;
        $i = 0;
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

                $image_title = $attachment->post_title;

                $image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full', true );
                $image_src = bfi_thumb( $image_src_array[ 0 ], array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height, 'crop'=>true));
                $image_src_thumb  = bfi_thumb( $image_src_array[ 0 ], array('width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'crop'=>true));

                $slide_item .= '<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="featured-image '.$hover_scenarios.'-hover">';
                $slide_item .= '<img width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" alt="'.$image_title.'" src="' . mk_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src, $width, $height) .'" />';
                $slide_item .= '<a href="'.$image_src_array[ 0 ].'" title="'.$image_title.'" rel="gallery-loop" class="mk-lightbox gallery-thumb-lightbox"><i class="mk-theme-icon-plus"></i></a>';
                $slide_item .= '</div></div>';

                $i++;
                if($i == 1 ) {
                    $first_loop_css = 'active-item';
                }

                $thumb_item .= '<a href="#" class="'.$first_loop_css.'">';
                $thumb_item .= '<img width="100" height="100" alt="'.$image_title.'" src="' . mk_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src_thumb, 100, 100) .'" />';
                $thumb_item .= '</a>';

                $first_loop_css = '';
            }


            $output .= '<div class="gallery-thumb-large"><div id="gallery-'.$id.'" class="swiper-container mk-swiper-slider" data-freeModeFluid="true" data-loop="false" data-slidesPerView="1" data-pagination="false" data-freeMode="false" data-mousewheelControl="true" data-direction="horizontal" data-slideshowSpeed="6000" data-animationSpeed="600" data-directionNav="true"><div class="swiper-wrapper">';
            $output .= $slide_item. '</div>';
            $output .= '<a class="mk-swiper-prev slideshow-swiper-arrows"><i class="mk-theme-icon-prev-big"></i></a>';
            $output .= '<a class="mk-swiper-next slideshow-swiper-arrows"><i class="mk-theme-icon-next-big"></i></a>';
            $output .= '</div></div>';
            $output .= '<div class="gallery-thumbs-small">' .$thumb_item. '</div>';

        }

        $final_output .= '<div style="max-width:'.$width.'px;margin-bottom:'.$margin_bottom.'px" class="mk-gallery '.$style.'-style '.$el_class.'">' . $output . '<div class="clearboth"></div></div>';
} else if($style == 'masonry'){

    $width = 750;
    $height = 750;
    $i = 0;
    $attachments = get_posts($args);

    $mansory_pointer_css = '';


    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            if($masonry_style == 'style1' && $i % 5 == 0) {
                $mansory_pointer_css .= 'gallery-mansory-large ';
            } else if($masonry_style == 'style2' && ($i - 2) % 5 == 0) {
                $mansory_pointer_css .= 'gallery-mansory-large ';
            }else if($masonry_style == 'style3' && ($i - 1) % 5 == 0) {
                $mansory_pointer_css .= 'gallery-mansory-large ';
            }else if($masonry_style == 'style4' && $i == 0) {
                $mansory_pointer_css .= 'gallery-mansory-large ';
            }

            $title = $attachment->post_title;
            $image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full', true );
            $image_src = bfi_thumb( $image_src_array[ 0 ], array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height, 'crop'=>true));

            $zoom_icon ='<a href="'.$image_src_array[0].'" title="'.$title.'" rel="gallery-'.$id.'" class="mk-lightbox theme-rounded-icon"><i class="mk-nuance-icon-search"></i></a>';
            $output .='<article class="mk-gallery-item mk-isotop-item masonry-'.$item_id.' '.$mansory_pointer_css.$scroller_css[2].'"'.$item_width.'><div class="item-holder" style="margin:0 '.$item_spacing.'px '.($item_spacing*2).'px">';

            $output .='<div class="featured-image '.$hover_scenarios.'-hover"><img alt="'.$title.'" title="'.$title.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="' . mk_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src, $width, $height) .'" />';
            $output .='<div class="hover-overlay"></div>';
                $output .='<a href="'.$image_src_array[0].'" title="'.$title.'" rel="gallery-'.$id.'" class="mk-lightbox">';
                $output .= '<div class="gallery-meta">';
                $output .= '<i class="mk-theme-icon-plus"></i><div class="clearboth"></div>';
                $output .= ($enable_title == 'true') ? '<div class="the-title">'.$title.'</div>' : '';
                $output .= '</div></a>';


            $output .='</div>';

            $output .='</div></article>';
            $i++;
            $mansory_pointer_css = '';
        }
        $final_output .= '<div class="loop-main-wrapper"><div id="gallery-'.$id.'" data-uniqid="'.$item_id.'" data-style="' . $style . '" style="margin-bottom:'.$margin_bottom.'px" class="mk-gallery isotop-enabled mk-theme-loop '.$style.'-style '.$scroller_css[0].$column_css.' '.$el_class.'"'.$scroller_css[3].'>' . $output . '</div></div>';
    }
}


wp_reset_query();


echo $final_output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line:

```
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
```

to this:

```
        'orderby' => 'rand',
```

Instead of showing the images in the same order as they were passed to `'post__in'`, they will show in random order each time the page is loaded.

Keep in mind that if you update the child theme, your change will be overwritten.

**EDIT:** The list of "pre selected images" is passed through the shortcode on the page where you want to display the gallery. If you don't want to pass a list of images, you could try commenting out this line (few lines above where you changed `'orderby'`):

```
        // 'post__in'=> explode( ',', $images ),
```

This will ignore any list of images you pass in the shortcode, and include all images on the site. In this case you may also want to adjust the following line:

```
        'numberposts' => -1
```

The -1 is for unlimited, but you could change it to something that makes sense for the gallery page, like 20 (or whatever number you want).

For additional parameters, such as excluding images, see the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, this is good but how do I load more images replacing existing?

Comment: From what you've posted, it looks like it would be through the shortcode on the page that displays the gallery.

Comment: Yes, its through the shortcode.

Comment: Are you asking how to include different images without having to change the shortcode?

Comment: You suggest whats the best method, as you understood the code.

Comment: You can ignore the image list passed from the shortcode, and just pull from all images on the site. See the edit to my answer.